# Problem changing system clock frequency

Tags: microcontroller, avr, microprocessor, avr-gcc

I have an ATtiny85 and I'm trying to set the clock to 8 MHz.  I have read the data sheet and some discussions on how to do this but am not having any luck getting it to work.  I have included my code and any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>


int main(void)
{
    cli();
    CLKPR |= 1<<CLKPCE;
    CLKPR |= 0;
    sei();

    DDRB |= 1<<PINB1 | 1<<PINB0;

    TCCR0A |= 1<<WGM00 | 1<<WGM01 | 1<<COM0B0 | 1<<COM0B1;
    TCCR0B |= 1<<CS00;
    OCR0B = 240;

    TCCR1 |= 1<<PWM1A | 1<<COM1A0 | 1<<CS13 | 1<<CS12 | 1<<CS11 | 1<<CS10; 
    OCR1C = 255; 
    OCR1A = 127;

    while (1)
    {
    }
}
```

I do not have a scope, so I'm not able to determine what the frequency of Timer0 is but I know that Timer1 is running at around 61 Hz (prescaler = CK/16384) because I timed the blinking of a led. That would mean that the CK is still at 1 MHz.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously I figure out what I was doing wrong after posting a question.  The following changes fixed it.

```
CLKPR = 0b10000000;
CLKPR = 0;
```

Comment: `#include <avr/power.h>`
`clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);`